# How do I get a suggestions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc

Is it possible to get pop-up suggestion while typing in google script for  functions created by user? Similar to built-in functions:  SpreadsheetApp. -->getActiveSheet() but for my functionName() to see arguments and type of return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. If you mean custom functions in the Google Script environment, then yes, you just need to create a library with your functions. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#creating_a_library) with instructions to create your own library. From the Libraries [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#using_a_library):

   > You can use your included library just as you would use a default service. For instance, if you have chosen Test as an identifier for your library, just type Test immediately followed by a period to see **autocomplete** information listing the methods of the library.

   By the way, the shortcut to see autocomplete is Ctrl+Space.
2. If you mean custom functions in Google Sheets, then yes you can. You just need to add a comment by following guidelines below. From the Autocomplete [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete):

   > Google Sheets supports autocomplete for custom functions much like for built-in functions. As you type a function name in a cell, you will see a list of built-in and custom functions that matches what you enter.
   >
   > Custom functions will appear in this list if their script includes a JsDoc @customfunction tag, as in the DOUBLE() example below.