# How to type hint Google Types in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, jsdoc

I am trying to typehint a bunch of javascript in Google Script, and I have gotten as far as trying this:

```
/**
 *  Get (named) range given by name
 *
 *  @param {String} name 
 *  @return {Range}
 *
 */
function getRange(name) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(name);
}
```

Which displays well and gives the same typehint as the builtin getRangeByName, however it does not actually work, i.e. the auto-complete script editor does not autocomplete when I type something like `getRange("hello").get"`, like it should. Should I be name spacing the `Range` or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Use [tag:clasp] with local [tag:ide]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, do you mean the Cntrl + Space autocomplete feature?

Comment: Off-note: is your `name` parameter really an instance of a `String` and not a string literal? When annotating with JSDoc, please, pay attention to what each type means, `string` and `String` do not mean the same thing.

Comment: also: you will need [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script) and yes, as TheMaster said, a local IDE and CLASP. You can't make the script editor magically know what the `Range` type is

Comment: @OlegValter thanks on the string note. I am a Python programmer by day, this is a side project. CLASP does seem the way forward, however surely there must be some way I can tell it what the `Range` is, because Google itself manages it? Surely if I matched what they write in their JSDoc for e.g. `SpreadsheetApp` methods, I could get the same behaviour?

Comment: @Cryvate - good luck doing that :) Even if you did manage to reproduce it somehow, I don't think it is worth the time and effort as Google could change that at any time. Better use an IDE such as VS Code and install a `@types/google-apps-script` npm package - your life will never be the same again. That said, Google plans to migrate to a new online editor that uses the same engine (Monaco), so when they release it, any effort poured into trying to work around current limitations will go to waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Google Apps Script IDE doesn't use local JSDOC to extend the autocomplete feature. Options:

1. Create a Goole Apps Script library and attach it to your project
2. Use another IDE

Regarding using another IDE at this time there is a tool called CLASP that helps to download/upload script which make it possible to use other IDEs.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp

Related

- [Google Apps Script Auto Generated Library Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15158745/1595451)
- [Is it possible to get the autocomplete functionality in AppsScript's script editor to work on custom classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28917654/1595451)
- [How do I get a suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47754087/1595451)

Other related

- [How to force newlines in Google Apps jsdoc descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28245463/1595451)

Comment: I am actually using a library as in the second link, so it is possible to get suggestions, but just not for types like `Range`?

Comment: @Cryvate I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Please bear in mind that JSDOC support in Google Apps Script IDE is limited.

Comment: So I have a library ScriptsLocal that I include in another script, and I can type hint a function in ScriptsLocal e.g. getRange(name) with name type `string` and its return type `Sheet`, and this will show up in the other script when I type ScriptsLocal.getRange. So the JSDOC is being picked up, but either my reference to `Sheet` is wrong (I tried things like `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet`) or I am doing something else wrong (using JSDOC wrong, as I said, I am not a JS programmer by trade).

Comment: Thanks. I have now done so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573838/how-to-type-hint-google-types-in-google-scripts-library

Answer (score 1):

One can add type hints for a plain old javascript object by defining a class for it, and adding a comment above the constructor defining the parameter types

[onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) (when a cell is edited) has an event, e as an input.
Unfortunately, it there is no Event type in the script editor.
We can fix that by defining an event class and adding a type hint for the parameter e like so:

```
class User {
   /**
    * @param {string} email
    * @param {string} nickname
    */
    constructor(email, nickname) {
    this.email = email;
    this.nickname = nickname;
  }
}

class Range {
   /**
    * @param {Number} columnEnd
    * @param {Number} columnStart
    * @param {Number} rowEnd
    * @param {Number} rowStart
    */
    constructor(columnEnd, columnStart, rowEnd, rowStart) {
    this.columnEnd = columnEnd;
    this.columnStart = columnStart;
    this.rowEnd = rowEnd;
    this.rowStart = rowStart;
  }
}

class Event {
   /**
    * @param {string} value
    * @param {User} user
    * @param {ScriptApp.AuthMode} authMode
    * @param {Range} range
    * @param {string} oldValue
    */
    constructor(value, user, authMode, range) {
    this.value = value;
    this.user = user;
    this.authMode = authMode;
    this.range = range;
  }
}

/**
* @param {Event} e
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  // now we have autocompletion on e properties
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(JSON.stringify(e));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e.user.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a name qualified with `SpreadsheetApp` works for me.

```
/**
 *  Get (named) range given by name
 *
 *  @param {String} name 
 *  @return {SpreadsheetApp.Range}
 *
 */
function getRange(name) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(name);
}
```